# Help differentiate long equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to differentiate the following equation twice with respect to $\alpha$. It is a profile log likelihood equation, where I need the derivatives to get the information matrix.

The equation is:
$\widetilde{L_\beta}(\alpha)=(1-\alpha)\sum\limits_{i=1}^m n_i\log\left(w_i/\hat{\sigma}_\alpha^2\right)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^m n_i\log \kappa_\alpha (-1/y_i)-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m 1_{\lbrace n_i \neq 0 \rbrace}\log\Gamma(-n_i\alpha) + n_+(\alpha-1)$,

where

$\hat{\sigma}_\alpha^2=\frac{-\sum\limits_{i=1}^m w_i \left\lbrace y_i \mu_i^{1/(\alpha-1)}(\alpha-1)-\kappa_\alpha (\mu_i^{1/(\alpha-1)}(\alpha-1)) \right\rbrace}{n_+(1-\alpha)}$

and

$\kappa_\alpha(\theta)=\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\left(\frac{\theta}{\alpha-1}\right)^\alpha$

I have tried for hours, and hours to do it, but this equation is just too hard for me, so if anyone could give me some hints how to split this up into simpler subproblems, that would be highly appreciated. Especially differentiating $\hat{\sigma}_\alpha^2$ gives me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Try a symbolic mathematical package such as maple? Also, this question is paramount to employing a human symbolic differentiation tool to do the grunt work..so I suggest using the first bit of my comment, and or, go and tough it out..

Comment: Do you want to derive twice with respect to alpha, correct? You got the first derivative with respect to alpha? It would be interesting if you write here the way you are trying to follow. Is not there some symmetry in their function or special property that make it easier the calculations enoug?

Comment: I do not have the first partial derivative, no. The kappa function and the gamma function does have some properties, which makes those easier. However, my main problem is the first term, and that does not have any properties to make the differentiation easier. And yes, I want the first and second partial derivative with respect to alpha